# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`age`' given input columns: [name, age];

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

Spark Version: 
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '2.4.4'
Java Version: 11.0.2

Csv File Content:

```
name, age
Paul, 25
```

I am simply testing if I can read the CSV file and check for how many records have been read with the following Java Test:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import scala.Serializable;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class SparkTest {
    public static class Person implements Serializable {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void createSpark_readText_returnOneRecord() {

        Encoder<Person> personEncoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class);

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Core")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Person> df = spark.read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(getClass().getResource("/person/person.csv").getPath())
                .as(personEncoder);

        assertThat(df.count(), is(1));

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Error stack trace:

---

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`age`' given input columns: [name,  age];

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$checkAnalysis$1$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$2(TreeNode.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUp$1(TreeNode.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$2(TreeNode.scala:346)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.$anonfun$iterator$3(MapLike.scala:257)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.foreach(IterableLike.scala:331)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force(TraversableViewLike.scala:91)
at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike.force$(TraversableViewLike.scala:89)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$$anon$1.force(IterableLike.scala:331)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:354)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$1(QueryPlan.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.$anonfun$mapExpressions$4(QueryPlan.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:258)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.deserializer$lzycompute(Dataset.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$deserializer(Dataset.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:430)
at mila.integration.SparkTest.createSpark_readText_returnPersonFirstName(SparkTest.java:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: What's in the header of the file,  i think "g" is different, if you check the error. Please check.

Comment: I have provided the content of the CSV file above. Are you saying "g" is different, as in different charset?

Comment: I just found the issue, CSV file has space (" ") in front of the 'age', therefore, the column name is actually (" " + 'age'. Is there are any way to trim this?

Comment: After reading the data, df =df.withColumnRenamed("age ", "age"). Probably before applying the encoder

Comment: The easiest way would be to remove the extra spaces from the csv file (especially since you are just testing).